# Bluetooth won't enable on Lenovo G560 under Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: indicator, bluetooth, 13.04, lenovo

I used to dualboot Win 7 and Ubuntu. When bluetooth was enabled under Win7, I had no problems using bluetooth in Ubuntu.

Now, Ubuntu 13.04 is my only OS and there is no bluetooth. All I can do is flick the switch in systemsettings, but it says, that bluetooth is "deactivated". I do not even have an icon in the menubar. I'm feeling very dumb right now -.-

[Update]
I did `sudo apt-get install synaptics` and installed additional software according to this question: [Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286834/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-04). The Indicator is back, but there is no functionality.

1. Bluetooth can not be switched on over the appindicator-menu
2. No devices are detected
3. Scannig for devices returns "no adapter" found error message

Comment: Read this:http://askubuntu.com/questions/286834/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-04
Works for me.I have Lenovo G570.

Comment: Thank you! This brought back the indicator applet. Therere is no funktionalty, though. Setting up a new devide gives me a "no adapter found" message.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that my solution didn't solved 100% your problem.I forgot to mention i have a usb bluetooh adapter(old one, bouth it 7 years ago), not a built-in laptop one.After you install the packages enable bluetooth and visibility from the standard menu, then for other settings, pairing devices and data transfers use only Blueman.Blueman icon appears in the up panel not in the unity bar.So, now i have 2 bluetooth icons in the panel in this order(in my case):Blueman-Mail-Battery-Stardard Ubuntu Bluetooth-Network-Sound-Date/Hour-Settings(with suspend, log out and all that stuff).

Comment: I (still) seem to have no funktionality on all of these settings. I can not enable bluetooth from the standard menu. Flicking the switch has no effect and the "visibility" switch is "inactive".

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a position where you can install windows again, I suggest you switch on bluetooth and wifi from windows and then do a clean full installation of Ubuntu 13.04.

Somehow from my experience it seems that the bios remembers only what happened when windows was connected even if there is no more windows.

I had the same problem with 12.10 and this fixed it.