# No Bluetooth adapter found on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, dell, bluetooth

I have tries almost everything but could not switch on Bluetooth and finally got to know Bluetooth adapter is not installed on my dell Inspiron N5010..

What I did..

1. Bios check - checked BIOS and Bluetooth is already enabled .
2. On windows - I switched it on and used to see if its a hardware issue, but its working on windows.
3. Bluetooth Manager - Installed it but did not worked out.

Useful Information to get my issue ..

result of `rfkill list all`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

result of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
13:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

Comment: @Mitch thanks I was trying to do the same , but it did not happened ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have a lot of experience  with bluetooth but I would try to make sure all my software is installed. This wiki suggest

```
sudo apt-get install bluez python-gobject python-dbus
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup

```
sudo apt-get install \
bluetooth blueman \
bluez-hcidump bluewho python-bluez  bluez-tools \
brcm-patchram-plus-nexus7
```

Is suggested by this another askubuntu post

[Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286834/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-04)

If the software doesn't fix it you may want to try one of the other solutions in that forum or consult the wiki.

Comment: yeah this time it worked.. thumbs up..