# Bluetooth adapter not found in HP Pavillion 15-e015tx ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 14.04, bluetooth

Earlier I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and my laptop was showing  "no Bluetooth adapters found" and Bluetooth icon was not appearing in the panel. Also WiFi switch (<kbd>F12</kbd>) was not getting on but still WiFi and ethernet were working fine. Now I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but the Bluetooth problem remains same.

My laptop is having Bluetooth driver:

```
07:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

and `rfkill list` output:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Could you check the output of `btmon` or `hcidump -X` while trying to bring your bluetooth adapter up? Some buggy bluetooth adapters report that they support the "Delete Stored Link Key" feature but in fact do not support it. If your adapter suffers from this issue, you'll probably have to use a custom kernel that works around this issue. Either you can apply the patch in the link below, or you can upgrade to Linux 3.14 or newer. Those bluetooth adapters worked with Kernels before 3.9, but this was just luck. Here's the link to the bug report: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60824

Comment: hcidump -X
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 2.5
Can't open device: No such device

Comment: Ok, this looks like a different issue then - one that I'm afraid I have no clue about...

Comment: I bought this laptop with windows 8 installed and bluetooth was working fine in windows 8 but it is not working in ubuntu 12.04/14.04.

Comment: "http://askubuntu.com/questions/379713/no-bluetooth-adapter-found-on-ubuntu-13-04?rq=1" After following this link, task bar is able to show bluetooth icon but still it is showing "No Bluetooth adapter found" and also there is no option for receiving and sending files using bluetooth.

Comment: It seems most likely that you will hit a dead end later as this card (Ralink RT 3290) doesn't have drivers for Linux and is a WiFi and Bluetooth combo card and a lot of people have failed to get this working since Ubuntu 12.04 (and on Windows too there are a lot of problems) came out. IMO, the best course of action is to try getting a new card (preferably Intel as they have awesome driver support).

Answer (score 0):

i'm using the same laptop. i to faced so many issues with Ubuntu14.04.
later the release of Ubuntu 15.10. i had installed 64bit version on my lab all my problem are solved. now it works good sorry for my bad english. if you have time just check and let me know thank you

Comment: Thanks for the response, now i am using latest centos 6 in my laptop and everything is working fine for me. I do n't want to use F**ng ubuntu.